# PHP how to get instantiated class name

Tags: php, function

im experimenting with some ways to retrieve data from my database.
I made an abstract class (ppdao) and in this class i have a function to build select queries based on a table name and turn the result into objects.

For each table i make a small file, like this :

```
class user extends ppdao{

public $table = 'user';    

public function __set ( $name, $value ){   
    $this->$name = $value;
}

public function __get ( $name ){
    return $this->$name;
}
```

Lets say i want all user objects in an array, i use the following function from my ppdao class :

```
public static function get_ar_obj( $arWhere = array() , $arWhereWay = array(), $order = null ){                
    $class = get_called_class();

    $obj = new $class();       
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM ".$obj->table. $obj->arWheretoString($arWhere);
    $res = mysqli_conn::getinstance()->query($sql)->all_assoc();         
    return $obj->createObjects($res);
}
```

This works all fine, it gives me back the wished results.

Now i changed the __get function a bit into this :

```
public function __get ( $name ){        
        switch ($name){
        case 'oAlbums':
             return $this->oAlbums = albums::get_ar_obj($arWhere = array('user_id' => $this->id) );
        break;

        default:
        return $this->$name;
        break;
}
```

I thought i want to get all albums a user have, in the album table there is a field called user_id , so i thought i'd link m together like this.

Now when i call the album class like this :

```
$userobject->oAlbums
```

get_called_class() is still using the user class name instead of the called album class, and thereby its creating a query like

```
SELECT * FROM user WHERE user_id = 63

And it should be SELECT * FROM album WHERE user_id = 63
```

Anyone have any idea's on how i can get this to work?

---

Im sorry people, it's not using get_called_class to create the query, its using the public $table . Got it working now by changing it into the get_called_class variable

This is the result:

```
$arUser = user::get_ar_obj( $arWhere = array('id' => 1));
$oUser = $arUser[0];

echo '<pre>';
    print_r($oUser->oAlbums);
echo '</pre>';
```

Outputs :

```
Array
(
    [0] => album Object
        (
            [table] => album
            [data:ppdao:private] => 
            [className:ppdao:private] => album
            [id] => 2
            [name] => My new album 1
            [slug] => my-new-album-1
            [user_id] => 1
            [views] => 0
            [datecreated] => 2013/03/23 16:00:43
            [location] => Muaha
        )
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, i've tested your code in [PHP 5.4.4](http://ideone.com/0OEZ9w) (at least I tried to reassemble it :D)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you had a look at the `static` keyword?  It will work on PHP5 >= 5.3

```
public static function get_ar_obj( $arWhere = array() , $arWhereWay = array(), $order = null ){                
    $obj = new static();       

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM ".$obj->table. $obj->arWheretoString($arWhere);
    $res = mysqli_conn::getinstance()->query($sql)->all_assoc();         
    return $obj->createObjects($res);
}
```